# Проблема с выводом значения переменной сессии после обновления страницы

Tags: php, сессия

Есть некая форма входа где пользователь вводит пароль и логин. В обработчике на неправильный ввод логина стоит что то типа :

```
$_SESSION["error_messages"] .= "<p class='mesage_error'>Пользователь с таким 
логином уже зарегистрирован</p>";
```

Сама форма входа что-то типа:

```
<form>
<input>
<input>
<div>if(isset($_SESSION["error_messages"])){
     echo $_SESSION["error_messages"];
     unset($_SESSION["error_messages"]);} 
</div> //Т.е грубо говоря див с выводом ошибки
<button>SEND</button>
</form>
```

Сама форма рабочая (код сверху просто для примера того как выглядит форма - 2 инпута, див с выводом ошибки и кнопка отправки данных)

Так вот если убрать unset то ошибка выводится, но не уничтожается после обновления страницы. А если оставить unset то не выводится сама ошибка.

Причем в другой форме точно такая же конструкция работает на ура.

Comment: а та, другая форма, она раньше этой на странице?

Comment: Она вообще на другой странице. Думаете все же стоит отделить котлеты от мух и переименовать переменные, которые выводят ошибки?

Comment: Переименовал. То же самое происходит. Стоит убрать unset выводится ошибка, а если оставить то пусто в поле вывода ошибки.

Comment: Может в форму передавать просто переменную с ошибкой `$errorMessages` Не используя сессию.